# SQL Query Joining Multiple tables using and critrea

Tags: sql, inner-join

When inner joining two tables the results are essentially "or" driven.  So for example if I had a parent and child table, and I wanted to know that children who have red or blond hair I would write something like:

```
SELECT parent.parent_name
FROM parent
INNER JOIN child
ON parent.parent_ID = child.parent_ID
WHERE child.hair = blond OR child.hair = red
```

This would tell me all parents who have children with red OR blond hair.  What would I write if I wanted to know parents who have at least one child with red hair AND at least one child with blond hair?  Keep in mind that the criteria may change over time - tomorrow I might want to know black and red and yellow and blond and green hair, so writing a query for red and a query for blond and joining the results wont work because sometimes it will be two ANDs, but sometimes more.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Look at using the having clause.  Group by distinct kids with that hair color if the count is 2 then they have one of each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great example of when to use a having clause.
You know you want at least one of each color so a distinct will be necessary.

The where clause limited to blond or red already. We grouped by parent so the having clause is only looking at each parents, not all kids; and if the distinct count is 2, then it must be because they have a child with blond hair and one with red hair.

Since you know the criteria each time (red, blond or red, green, yellow blond), the count can vary as well via parameters!

```
SELECT parent.parent_name
FROM parent
INNER JOIN child
ON parent.parent_ID = child.parent_ID
WHERE child.hair = blond OR child.hair = red
group by parent.parent_name 
Having count(Distinct child.hair) = 2
```

so as your where clause changes so does the #2.

Comment: That is great.  Thanks so much.  First in. But I chose to accept the latter answer for three reasons:
1 - More complete having added test data
2 - Using In vs Where + Or saves code
3 - >1 vs =2 in Having means no need to adjust the count
I hope that is ok. Your answer was great and fast too.

Comment: Oh shoot, I'm wrong.  = is the correct way to go because if I put in 3 criteria (Red, Yellow, Black) it has to be exactly 3 to get all of the and conditions.

Comment: You can combine both and include a IN for child hair instead of using the or's if you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably hit the child table twice, once for blond and once for red:

```
SELECT parent.parent_name
FROM parent
INNER JOIN child BlondChild
ON parent.parent_ID = Blondchild.parent_ID
and Blondchild.hair = 'blond'
inner join chile RedChild
on parent.parent_id = RedChild.parentid
and RedChild.hair = 'red'
```

Answer (score 0):

Great case to use GROUP BY, HAVING & DISTINCT all in one query. Made up some sample data should you not already have a table. Currently the HAVING clause is looking for at least 2 kids being found in the list, obviously you could adjust as needed. Sample data for MSSQL just to play with if desired with some temp tables.

```
DECLARE @tParents table (ParentID int
                        ,Parent_Name nvarchar(25))

DECLARE @tChildren table (ChildID int
                            ,ParentID int
                            ,Child_Name nvarchar(25)
                            ,HairColor nvarchar(10))

INSERT INTO @tParents (ParentID,Parent_Name)
    SELECT 1,'Wilma'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Betty'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3,'Fred'
    UNION ALL SELECT 4,'Barney' 

INSERT INTO @tChildren (ChildID,ParentID,Child_Name,HairColor)
    SELECT 1,1,'Jack','Blonde'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,'Sue','Red'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3,1,'Larry','Green'
    UNION ALL SELECT 4,2,'Billy','Blonde'
    UNION ALL SELECT 5,2,'Molly','Green'
    UNION ALL SELECT 6,3,'Ryan','Brown'
    UNION ALL SELECT 7,4,'Scott','Brown'
    UNION ALL SELECT 8,4,'Josh','Brown'
    UNION ALL SELECT 9,4,'Mort','Green'
    UNION ALL SELECT 10,4,'Patrick','Red'

SELECT parent.Parent_Name
FROM @tParents parent 
INNER JOIN @tChildren child ON parent.ParentID = child.ParentID
WHERE child.HairColor IN ('Blonde','Green')
GROUP BY parent.Parent_Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(child.HairColor)) > 1
```

Comment: Took way to long to type as I got distracted by work, looks like xQbert beat me to actually posting up the answer.

Comment: same answer but a bit more complete. Thanks so much. I think I need to give it to xQbert for primacy. Is there a way to accept both answers?

Comment: actually I moved the check down to yours because the >1 prevents me from having to adjust for the count vs the equals.

Comment: Oh shoot, I'm wrong.  = is the correct way to go because if I put in 3 criteria (Red, Yellow, Black) it has to be exactly 3 to get all of the and conditions.